# how to resize base64 image to 300*300 before upload in php?

Tags: php, image, upload, resize, base64

When i uploading photo i want to resize base64 image to  300*300   before  upload .. How do I do this?

i treid to upload without resizing. but some of image can be big. i want to resize them.

```
    $folderPath = "uploads/";

    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $_POST['Image']);

    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);

    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];

    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);

    $file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.png';


    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
```

Comment: If you want to do it _before_ the upload, then you have to do it on the client. Keywords like “javascript resize image before upload” or similar should get you plenty results to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `imagecreatefromstring($image_base64);` to create GD image and then resize it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can upload image after resizing it using the code below.**

```
imageResizeUpload('your_base64_image','custom_prefix_for_image_name','destination_path_for_image');


public function imageResizeUpload($image, $namePrefix, $destination)
    {
        list($type, $file) = explode(';', $image);
        list(, $extension) = explode('/', $type);
        list($dd , $file) = explode(',', $file);
        $image_resource = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($file));
        $resized_image = imagescale($image_resource, 500,300);
        $fileNameToStore = $namePrefix . rand(1, 100000000) . '.' . $extension;
        imagejpeg($resized_image, $destination.$fileNameToStore);
        return $fileNameToStore;
    }
```